# Datasheet view bug in Explorer 11 and Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint-2010

The organisation works with Internet Exploler 11 & Edge, and not everyone is able to open the list in datasheet view.

One possible workaround is to enable the compatibility mode in explorer. But I'm not sure for how long this solution will work.

Has anyone a better solution for this problem?

We are using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 11 is supported for SharePoint 2010, but you must add the SharePoint sites to Compatibility View to make some features work.

For reference, see Microsoft's official browser support documentation: **[Plan browser support (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.14).aspx)**.

Relevant excerpts:

> ### Note
>
> Internet Explorer 11 edge mode is not supported. Add sites to the **Compatibility View** list to make some features work.

Additionally, note that only the 32-bit version of Internet Explorer (not the 64-bit version) is compatible with the ActiveX controls required for Datasheet view:

> ### ActiveX controls
>
> Some functionality in SharePoint Server 2010 requires the use of ActiveX controls. This produces limitations on browsers which do not support ActiveX. Currently only 32-bit versions of Internet Explorer support this functionality. All other browsers have the following limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We think adding sitest to the compatibility view is just a temporary solution. Maybe the best way is to force the page using IE 10 with the compability meta tag in de html header.

Comment: Yes, that's a good, valid way to force the browser into compatibility view. For best results, force it to emulate IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed 2010 datasheet view by installing

[2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)